# How to convert special characters in PHP

Tags: php

I have a word with a special character in it that does not display properly in the subject line of an email (via mail()).

The word is O’Conner and the special character is ’

"as is" the word appears as `O&#8217;Conner` in the subject line of the incoming email message.

When I use html_entities_decode()the word appears as `Oâ€™Conner` in the subject line of the incoming email message.

When I use mb_encode_mimeheader("O’Conner", "UTF-8", "Q") the word appears as `O&#8217;Conner` in the subject line of the incoming email message.

Is there a way to get the word to appear is it should?

Comment: Make sure you send the email as UTF-8 encoded and that all your PHP files also are stored as UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, that link to the other supposed SO answer does not work. `mb_encode_mimeheader("O'Conner", 'UTF-8', 'Q')` does not do the trick!

Comment: If it shows “O&#8217;Conner”, that’s because the string is *actually* “O&#8217;Conner”. If you don’t want it to include an HTML entity, then don’t put one in it. Why is it HTML encoded in the first place? HTML-decode it if you have to, as you’ve already tried.